# Select all by class except last

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a series of `div` and I would like to select all `p` tags with `enable` class except the last inside each div in order to apply a specific style in css. The content are dynamically generated and may vary depending on the user.

In the example below, I would like to apply this style to the first two `p` inside the first div and none inside the other. I'm sure it's pretty easy but I don't find any solution to solve it.

```
<div>
    <p class="enable"></p>
    <p class="enable"></p>
    <p class="enable"></p>
    <p class="disable"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="enable"></p>
    <p class="disable"></p>
    <p class="disable"></p>
    <p class="disable"></p>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no solution for this in CSS.

Comment: @Axanagor Will p.disable and the last p.enable have the same styles?

Answer (score 0):

If the `p` elements are confined to four per `div` you can use the `nth-child` pseudo selector.

```
p.enable:nth-child(-n+2)
{
    background: #0f0;
}

p.disable
{
    background: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/vw4wQ/

Comment: first p tag inside second div should not be highlighted, I think as per the requirement.

Comment: Then you're asking too much of CSS and will have to resort to some kind of messed up javascript. Good luck.

Comment: This is not my question. I just saw what as asked and what was provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Javascript solution for you:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"), paras, i, j;

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    paras = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(j = 0; j < paras.length-1; j++) {
        if(paras[j+1].className === "disable")
            break;
        // apply your custom code here
        paras[j].style.background = "#FF0000";
    }
}
```

Check this solution in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8M5kE/)

Comment: this question is no where tagged as jquery or javascript

Comment: @defau1t: I know, but I saw that way to late and did not want my answer to go to waste.

Comment: anyways i dont think it is possible in css alone.